# Is there a way to follow HATEOAS links / reuse responses within JMeter when API testing?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm looking for a way to use the contents of links when testing an API, e.g.

```
GET /list-products/
{
  "_links": {
    "item": [
      {
        "href": "/items/item1’",
        "name": "item1",
        "title": "Item 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "list-products",
  "title": "Product List"
}
```

I'd like to dynamically use part of the response in other calls to be tested, such as `GET /get-orders/$itemName` -> `GET /get-orders/item1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract this `/items/item1` from the response and store it into a JMeter Variable called `itemName` take the following steps:

1. Add [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: `itemName`
   - JSON JMESPath expressions: `_links.item[0].name`
   - Match No: `1`

   [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted item name as `${itemName}` later on where required

JSON JMESPath Extractor allows executing [JMESPath language queries](https://jmespath.org/) so you can easily extract "interesting" parts from JSON responses. See [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) article for more information if needed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I'm now running into: `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 37: http://localhost:8080/get-orders/{$itemName}`, I assume it's not really picking the response up. Could it be that both of the requests are running under different thread groups? If so, how can I elevate its scope?

Comment: Solved with the use of a BeanShell Assertion to make it available to other thread groups. Thanks Dmitri.